# Fractal tilings and Fundamental Domains

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, geometric-topology, fractals

The following excerpt comes from the Wikipedia article on fundamental domains:

"Given a topological space and a group acting on it, the images of a single point under the group action form an orbit of the action. A **fundamental domain** is a subset of the space which contains exactly one point from each of these orbits."

My question mostly stems from a lack of understanding of the definition, but here it is:

Q: Does a self-similar fractal tile form a fundamental domain in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

For example, the famous dragon curve (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_curve) can be used to form the boundary of a fractal that can tile the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$. Specifically, I am interested in the tile found in this article; see page 84 for the picture. [https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~wgilbert/Research/MathIntel.pdf](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ewgilbert/Research/MathIntel.pdf)

To state the question simply, are these tiles fundamental domains?

Comment: Fundamental domain of *what*?  $\mathbb{R}^2$ is your topological space.  What is your group?  that is, which group is acting on $\mathbb{R}^2$?